# How to change Button's border colors?

Tags: vb.net, button, colors, border

I'm new to Visual Basic and I want to change the border color of a `Button`, but I don't see any option to do that in the IDE (Visual Studio 2017). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way to do this is not very obvious as the default `Button` doesn't allow for a coloured border.

First you have to set the `Button`'s `FlatStyle` property to `FlatStyle.Flat`. Then you have to set the `Button`'s `FlatAppearance.BorderColor` property to the colour of your choice.

You can do both of those things in the Visual Studio form designer if you want, or you can do it in code like this:

```
Button1.Flatstyle = FlatStyle.Flat
Button1.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Yellow
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this is a few different ways. One option (***quick and easy***) is to subclass the `System.Windows.Forms.Button` class and then override the `OnPaint`method...

For example:

```
 Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal pevent As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(pevent)
        Dim rect As New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height)
        Dim mPen As New Pen(Color.Red, 3)
        pevent.Graphics.DrawRectangle(mPen, rect)
    End Sub
```

Another option is to create your own button control, this takes time and you could benefit better as you would have more control in what you would like to do. If your button's `FlatStyle` property is set to "Flat" you could change the `FlatApperance` property in designer such as border-size and etc...

Answer (score 1):

```
Button1.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Red
```